# What would be the pressure, temperature and density gradients with altitude of atmosphere with ideal gas?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, atmospheric-science, kinetic-theory

What would be the pressure, temperature and density gradients with altitude of atmosphere with ideal gas considerations? That is no convection or radiation.
Most of the answers I have seen are assuming the pressure gradient is equal to the weight of the gas between the point. But why? If we assume ideal gas, it should be only aware of the density and velocity of the gas adjacent to it. isn't it?